# How to split .txt file at specific location and import each part as table in r

Tags: r, split

I have huge text file containing records for chemicals. Each entry starts with "*NEWRECORD" and ends with blank line. I don't know how many records are there. Rows for each records varies. How can I save each record as a separate data frame?

Here below example of my text file

```
imported_data <- c("*NEWRECORD
   SH = diagnostic imaging
   QE = DIAG IMAGE
   QA = DG
   QT = 1
   QX = X-ray|NRW
   UI = Q000000981

   *NEWRECORD
   RECTYPE = Q
   SH = analogs & derivatives
   QE = ANALOGS
   QA = AA
   QT = 1

   *NEWRECORD
   RECTYPE = Q
   SH = abnormalities
   QE = ABNORM
   QX = agenesis|NRW
   QX = anomalies|EQV
   QX = aplasia|NRW
   QX = atresia|NRW
   QX = birth defects|NRW
   QX = congenital defects|NRW
   QX = defects|NRW
   QX = deformities|NRW
   QX = hypoplasia|NRW
   UI = Q000002")

# What I expect is

# Table_1
# SH                    QE         QA   QT   QX         UI
# diagnostic imaging   DIAG IMAGE  DG   1    X-ray|NRW  Q000000981

# Table_2
# RECTYPE   SH                     QE        QA     QT
# Q         analogs & derivatives  ANALOGS   AA     1

# and so on ...
```

Comment: What do you expect for the third record? Is there other cases of a replicated keyword (like 'QX')?

Comment: You've not indicated how you want to handle the record with multiple `QX` entries nor have you indicated if other fields can be repeating. Also, there are more than  a few SO questions that deal with splitting a file, iterating over the parts, and making a data frame from it, so which ones did not provide sufficient info?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringi)
library(purrr)

lines <- readLines("~/Data/so.txt")

head(lines)

# find start/end positions of all the records
starts <- which(stri_detect_fixed(lines, "*NEWRECORD"))
ends <- c(starts[-1], length(lines))

map2(starts, ends, ~{

  # extract the bits to work on
  rec <- stri_trim_both(lines[.x:.y]) 

  # filter out unimportant bits
  rec <- rec[!(stri_detect_regex(rec, "^$|NEWRECORD"))]

  # get the field/value pairs  
  rec <- stri_split_regex(rec, "[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*", simplify = FALSE)

  # make a container
  out <- list()

  # add to the container, increasing vector size of an element if necessary
  for(r in rec) out[[ r[1] ]] <- c(out[[ r[1] ]], r[2])

  # assume only QX is repeated since the OP neglected to provide that info
  # also assume QX should be a list column since the OP also neglected to provide that info
  if ("QX" %in% names(out)) out[["QX"]] <- list(out[["QX"]])

  as_data_frame(out)

})
```

Which produces:

```
## [[1]]
## # A tibble: 1 x 6
##   SH                 QE         QA    QT    QX        UI        
##   <chr>              <chr>      <chr> <chr> <list>    <chr>     
## 1 diagnostic imaging DIAG IMAGE DG    1     <chr [1]> Q000000981
## 
## [[2]]
## # A tibble: 1 x 5
##   RECTYPE SH                    QE      QA    QT   
##   <chr>   <chr>                 <chr>   <chr> <chr>
## 1 Q       analogs & derivatives ANALOGS AA    1    
## 
## [[3]]
## # A tibble: 1 x 5
##   RECTYPE SH            QE     QX        UI     
##   <chr>   <chr>         <chr>  <list>    <chr>  
## 1 Q       abnormalities ABNORM <chr [9]> Q000002
```

We can also get one big data frame (nested `QX` column):

```
(map2_df(starts, ends, ~{
  rec <- stri_trim_both(lines[.x:.y]) 
  rec <- rec[!(stri_detect_regex(rec, "^$|NEWRECORD"))]
  rec <- stri_split_regex(rec, "[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*", simplify = FALSE)
  out <- list()
  for(r in rec) out[[ r[1] ]] <- c(out[[ r[1] ]], r[2])
  if ("QX" %in% names(out)) out[["QX"]] <-list(out[["QX"]])
  as_data_frame(out)
}) -> xdf)
## # A tibble: 3 x 7
##   SH                    QE         QA    QT    QX        UI       RECTYPE
##   <chr>                 <chr>      <chr> <chr> <list>    <chr>    <chr>  
## 1 diagnostic imaging    DIAG IMAGE DG    1     <chr [1]> Q000000… NA     
## 2 analogs & derivatives ANALOGS    AA    1     <NULL>    NA       Q      
## 3 abnormalities         ABNORM     NA    NA    <chr [9]> Q000002  Q
```

Or take ^^ and unnest the `QX` column:

```
# one row per QX
mutate(xdf, QX = map(QX, ~if (is.null(.x)) NA_character_ else .x)) %>% 
  unnest(QX)
## # A tibble: 11 x 7
##    SH                    QE         QA    QT    UI         RECTYPE QX                    
##    <chr>                 <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr>   <chr>                 
##  1 diagnostic imaging    DIAG IMAGE DG    1     Q000000981 NA      X-ray|NRW             
##  2 analogs & derivatives ANALOGS    AA    1     NA         Q       NA                    
##  3 abnormalities         ABNORM     NA    NA    Q000002    Q       agenesis|NRW          
##  4 abnormalities         ABNORM     NA    NA    Q000002    Q       anomalies|EQV         
##  5 abnormalities         ABNORM     NA    NA    Q000002    Q       aplasia|NRW           
##  6 abnormalities         ABNORM     NA    NA    Q000002    Q       atresia|NRW           
##  7 abnormalities         ABNORM     NA    NA    Q000002    Q       birth defects|NRW     
##  8 abnormalities         ABNORM     NA    NA    Q000002    Q       congenital defects|NRW
##  9 abnormalities         ABNORM     NA    NA    Q000002    Q       defects|NRW           
## 10 abnormalities         ABNORM     NA    NA    Q000002    Q       deformities|NRW       
## 11 abnormalities         ABNORM     NA    NA    Q000002    Q       hypoplasia|NRW
```

Or, go back and make a single data frame with `QX` spread out:

```
map2_df(starts, ends, ~{
  rec <- stri_trim_both(lines[.x:.y]) 
  rec <- rec[!(stri_detect_regex(rec, "^$|NEWRECORD"))]
  rec <- stri_split_regex(rec, "[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*", simplify = TRUE)
  as.list(set_names(rec[,2], make.names(rec[,1], unique=TRUE)))
})
## # A tibble: 3 x 15
##   SH     QE     QA    QT    QX     UI     RECTYPE QX.1  QX.2  QX.3  QX.4  QX.5  QX.6  QX.7  QX.8 
##   <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
## 1 diagn… DIAG … DG    1     X-ray… Q0000… NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
## 2 analo… ANALO… AA    1     NA     NA     Q       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
## 3 abnor… ABNORM NA    NA    agene… Q0000… Q       anom… apla… atre… birt… cong… defe… defo… hypo…
```

Comment: this works, I just now need to work on QX, because this column is repeating and I want this column. I need to save each dataframe in my r environment

Comment: Yeah lets go untested @hrbrmstr. Ultimate goal is to use rbind.fill to rbind all these dataframes.

Comment: Yes I want to make a single dataset out of this all @hrbrmstr Will it be possible to add QX.1, QX.2 ...so on for each of the QX?

Comment: that works well. Just last question, what if along with QX there are more columns that are repeated e.g. "TN" (not shown in above example)

Comment: I tried c("QX","TN") but it doesn't let me use more than one column name in if command. The original file (q2018.bin) can be obtained from ftp://nlmpubs.nlm.nih.gov/online/mesh/MESH_FILES/asciimesh/

Comment: ah, you may want to look at http://ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/R/library/AnnBuilder/html/MeSHParser.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is perhaps some start of a solution :

```
library(tidyverse)

imported_data %>% str_split("\\*NEWRECORD") -> l
l[[1]][-1] %>%
  purrr::map(
    function(x) data.frame(z=str_split(x,"\n")[[1]][-1]) %>%
                filter(str_detect(z,"="))
  ) %>%
  purrr::map(
    function(x) separate(x,z,c("k","v")," = ",extra="merge") %>%
                mutate(k=str_replace_all(k," ",""))
  )

#[[1]]
#   k                  v
#1 SH diagnostic imaging
#2 QE         DIAG IMAGE
#3 QA                 DG
#4 QT                  1
#5 QX          X-ray|NRW
#6 UI         Q000000981

#[[2]]
#        k                     v
#1 RECTYPE                     Q
#2      SH analogs & derivatives
#3      QE               ANALOGS
#4      QA                    AA
#5      QT                     1

#[[3]]
#         k                      v
#1  RECTYPE                      Q
#2       SH          abnormalities
#3       QE                 ABNORM
#4       QX           agenesis|NRW
#5       QX          anomalies|EQV
#6       QX            aplasia|NRW
#7       QX            atresia|NRW
#8       QX      birth defects|NRW
#9       QX congenital defects|NRW
#10      QX            defects|NRW
#11      QX        deformities|NRW
#12      QX         hypoplasia|NRW
#13      UI                Q000002
```

To get only one data frame from all of these, an option could be :

```
imported_data %>% 
  str_split("\\*NEWRECORD") -> l
l[[1]][-1] %>%
   purrr::map(function(x) data.frame(z=str_split(x,"\n")[[1]][-1]) %>%
                          filter(str_detect(z,"="))) %>%
   purrr::map(function(x) separate(x,z,c("k","v")," = ",extra="merge") %>%
                          mutate(k=str_replace_all(k," ","")) %>%
                          group_by(k) %>%
                          summarise(v= paste(v,collapse=", ")) %>%
                          spread(k,v)
   ) %>% purrr::reduce(bind_rows)
## A tibble: 3 x 7
#  QA    QE         QT    QX                                                                                                                                        SH                   UI        RECTYPE
#  <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr>                                                                                                                                 <chr>                <chr>     <chr>  
#1 DG    DIAG IMAGE 1     X-ray|NRW                                                                                                                             diagnostic imaging   Q0000009~ <NA>   
#2 AA    ANALOGS    1     <NA>                                                                                                                                  analogs & derivativ~ <NA>      Q      
#3 <NA>  ABNORM     <NA>  agenesis|NRW, anomalies|EQV, aplasia|NRW, atresia|NRW, birth defects|NRW, congenital defects|NRW, defects|NRW, deformities|NRW, hypo~ abnormalities        Q000002   Q
```

Comment: Thanx @Nicolas2. There are repetitive column names. Actually this code didn't work. The separation of 2 columns is based on "=" sign but there are rows where there are more than one "=" signs in second column. Thus it split such a rows in more than 2 columns. I remove first row "RECTYPE" "Q", now all rows starts with two capital letters (which is our first column) and equal sign that separate rest of the information (our second column). How will I modify your code? I tried "[A-Z]{2} = " instead of " = " but that didn't helped.

Comment: Perhaps with `extra="merge"`in the call to `separate` : it will split only on the first occurence of ` = ` (I edited my anwser) . Or with `(?<=[A-Z]{2}) = `, following your suggestion, if you are sure enough that such patterns cannot appear in your data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to save each dataframe in my r workspace and later I want to rbind.fill to rbind each of these dataframe

Comment: Not sure what you want without an example!  I edited my answer to get a single table (rbind/bind_rows) at the end of the process.

Comment: I got error Error in eval_tidy(enquo(var), var_env) : object 'k' not found

Comment: Please check your code step by step : it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the above answer to "show the work" for others but you can now do:

```
devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/whatamesh")
```

and then do this to list the files on the site:

```
list_mesh_files()
## # A tibble: 3 x 3
##   `Size (Bytes)` `Last Modified` File     
##   <chr>          <chr>           <chr>    
## 1 98499407       Oct 15 04:38    c2018.bin
## 2 29052512       Jul 16 04:31    d2018.bin
## 3 85614          Jul 16 04:30    q2018.bin
```

If the file is local it'll read it locally otherwise it'll download and read it:

```
read_mesh_file("q2018.bin")
## # A tibble: 79 x 16
##    RECTYPE SH                       QE    QA    QT    MS    AN    HN    QX    DA    MR    DQ    UI    OL    TN    QS   
##    <chr>   <chr>                    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <lis> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <lis> <chr>
##  1 Q       diagnostic imaging       DIAG… DG    1     Used… subh… 2017… <chr… 2016… 2016… 2017… Q000… <NA>  <NUL… <NA> 
##  2 Q       abnormalities            ABNO… AB    1     Used… subh… 66; … <chr… 1973… 2015… 1966… Q000… sear… <chr… <NA> 
##  3 Q       administration & dosage  ADMIN AD    1     Used… "sub… 66; … <chr… 1973… 2017… 1966… Q000… sear… <chr… ADMI…
##  4 Q       adverse effects          ADV … AE    1     Used… subh… 66; … <chr… 1973… 2017… 1966… Q000… sear… <chr… <NA> 
##  5 Q       analogs & derivatives    ANAL… AA    1     Used… subh… 75; … <chr… 1974… 2017… 1975… Q000… sear… <chr… <NA> 
##  6 Q       analysis                 ANAL  AN    1     "Use… "sub… 67; … <chr… 1973… 2003… 1967… Q000… sear… <chr… <NA> 
##  7 Q       anatomy & histology      ANAT  AH    1     Used… subh… 66; … <chr… 1973… 2017… 1966… Q000… sear… <chr… ANAT…
##  8 Q       antagonists & inhibitors ANTAG AI    1     Used… subh… 68; … <chr… 1973… 2017… 1968… Q000… sear… <chr… <NA> 
##  9 Q       biosynthesis             BIOS… BI    1     Used… "sub… 66; … <chr… 1973… 2003… 1966… Q000… sear… <chr… <NA> 
## 10 Q       blood                    BLOOD BL    1     "Use… "sub… 67; … <NUL… 1973… 2003… 1967… Q000… sear… <chr… <NA> 
## # ... with 69 more rows
```

It supports "wide" format, too:

```
read_mesh_file("q2018.bin", wide = TRUE)
## # A tibble: 79 x 108
##    RECTYPE SH     QE    QA    QT    MS    AN    HN    QX    QX.1  QX.2  QX.3  QX.4  QX.5  QX.6  QX.7  QX.8  QX.9  QX.10
##    <chr>   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
##  1 Q       diagn… DIAG… DG    1     Used… subh… 2017… X-ra… X-ra… X-ra… echo… echo… radi… radi… radi… roen… ultr… ultr…
##  2 Q       abnor… ABNO… AB    1     Used… subh… 66; … agen… anom… apla… atre… birt… cong… defe… defo… hypo… malf… <NA> 
##  3 Q       admin… ADMIN AD    1     Used… "sub… 66; … admi… <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
##  4 Q       adver… ADV … AE    1     Used… subh… 66; … side… <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
##  5 Q       analo… ANAL… AA    1     Used… subh… 75; … anal… deri… <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
##  6 Q       analy… ANAL  AN    1     "Use… "sub… 67; … assa… chem… dete… <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
##  7 Q       anato… ANAT  AH    1     Used… subh… 66; … anat… anat… hist… morp… <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
##  8 Q       antag… ANTAG AI    1     Used… subh… 68; … anta… anta… inhi… <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
##  9 Q       biosy… BIOS… BI    1     Used… "sub… 66; … anab… biof… <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
## 10 Q       blood  BLOOD BL    1     "Use… "sub… 67; … <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
## # ... with 69 more rows, and 89 more variables: QX.11 <chr>, DA <chr>, MR <chr>, DQ <chr>, UI <chr>, OL <chr>,
## #   TN <chr>, TN.1 <chr>, TN.2 <chr>, TN.3 <chr>, TN.4 <chr>, TN.5 <chr>, TN.6 <chr>, TN.7 <chr>, TN.8 <chr>,
## #   TN.9 <chr>, TN.10 <chr>, TN.11 <chr>, TN.12 <chr>, QS <chr>, TN.13 <chr>, TN.14 <chr>, TN.15 <chr>, TN.16 <chr>,
## #   TN.17 <chr>, TN.18 <chr>, TN.19 <chr>, TN.20 <chr>, TN.21 <chr>, TN.22 <chr>, TN.23 <chr>, TN.24 <chr>,
## #   TN.25 <chr>, TN.26 <chr>, TN.27 <chr>, TN.28 <chr>, TN.29 <chr>, TN.30 <chr>, TN.31 <chr>, TN.32 <chr>,
## #   TN.33 <chr>, TN.34 <chr>, TN.35 <chr>, TN.36 <chr>, TN.37 <chr>, TN.38 <chr>, TN.39 <chr>, TN.40 <chr>,
## #   TN.41 <chr>, TN.42 <chr>, TN.43 <chr>, TN.44 <chr>, TN.45 <chr>, TN.46 <chr>, TN.47 <chr>, TN.48 <chr>,
## #   TN.49 <chr>, TN.50 <chr>, TN.51 <chr>, TN.52 <chr>, TN.53 <chr>, TN.54 <chr>, TN.55 <chr>, TN.56 <chr>,
## #   TN.57 <chr>, TN.58 <chr>, TN.59 <chr>, TN.60 <chr>, TN.61 <chr>, TN.62 <chr>, TN.63 <chr>, TN.64 <chr>,
## #   TN.65 <chr>, TN.66 <chr>, TN.67 <chr>, TN.68 <chr>, TN.69 <chr>, TN.70 <chr>, TN.71 <chr>, TN.72 <chr>,
## #   TN.73 <chr>, TN.74 <chr>, TN.75 <chr>, TN.76 <chr>, TN.77 <chr>, TN.78 <chr>, QX.12 <chr>, QX.13 <chr>, QX.14 <chr>
```

And, will work with the other two large files as well (it takes a while to d/l and takes a while to parse them).

It should handle all the defined repeating columns for the MeSH format.

Pls [file issues](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/whatamesh/issues) if anything breaks vs post here.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one way:

```
library(dplyr)
split1 <- strsplit(imported_data, "\\*NEWRECORD") %>% unlist()
split2 <- split1
if(sum (0==nchar(split1))>0)  split2 <- split1[-which(0==nchar(split1))]

split3 <- strsplit(split2, "\\n")

split4 <- lapply(split3, function(x) strsplit(x, " = "))
split5 <- split4[lapply(split4,length)>0]  #lapply(split4, function(x) if(sum(length(x)==0)>0) {x[-which(length(x)==0)]} else x )

lapply(split4, nchar)
length(split4[[3]][[2]])

is.null( split4[[3]][[1]])

split5 <- lapply(split4, function(x) ifelse(lapply(x, function(y) length(y) >0), x, ""))
split6 <- lapply(split5, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) gsub(" ", "", y)))
split7 <- lapply(split6, function(x) x[nzchar(x)])

lapply(split6, length)

dim1 <- length(split7)
dim2 <- lapply(split7, length) %>% unlist()
dim3 <- lapply(split7, function(x) lapply(x, length) ) %>% unlist()

listres <-  list()

for( i in 1:length(dim2)) {
  mat <- matrix(NA, dim2[i], 2)
  mat <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(split7[[i]]), nrow= dim2[i], byrow=T))# %>% t()
  dim(mat)
  names(mat) <- c("varname", "value")
  mat <- t(mat)
  colnames(mat) <- mat[1,]
  mat <- mat[-1,]
  listres[[i]] <- mat
}
listres

[[1]]
                 SH                  QE                  QA                  QT 
"diagnosticimaging"         "DIAGIMAGE"                "DG"                 "1" 
                 QX                  UI 
        "X-ray|NRW"        "Q000000981" 

[[2]]
              RECTYPE                    SH                    QE 
                  "Q" "analogs&derivatives"             "ANALOGS" 
                   QA                    QT 
                 "AA"                   "1" 

[[3]]
                RECTYPE                      SH                      QE 
                    "Q"         "abnormalities"                "ABNORM" 
                     QX                      QX                      QX 
         "agenesis|NRW"         "anomalies|EQV"           "aplasia|NRW" 
                     QX                      QX                      QX 
          "atresia|NRW"      "birthdefects|NRW" "congenitaldefects|NRW" 
                     QX                      QX                      QX 
          "defects|NRW"       "deformities|NRW"        "hypoplasia|NRW" 
                     UI 
              "Q000002"
```

You now have a list with n data frames as specified.

EDIT: the table 1 in your post is found using `data.frame(listres[[1]]) %>% t()`

```
                 SH                  QE                  QA                  QT 
"diagnosticimaging"         "DIAGIMAGE"                "DG"                 "1" 
                 QX                  UI 
        "X-ray|NRW"        "Q000000981"
```

and so on for the other data frames.

Comment: Thre are no data frames in that structure you presented.

Comment: see edits, you just need to take individual elements in the list to get your expected result.

Comment: but…the OP _wanted_ a data frame. your edits _still_ haven't provided that